# Cannot Click button when table row with button is appended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

https://jsfiddle.net/r7a2r9eL/

```
$('#insertBtn').click( function(){
    $('#mytable > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td>'+$('#fnameText').val()+'</td><td>'+$('#lnameText').val()+'</td><td>'+$('#pointText').val()+'</td><td><button type="button" class="deleteClass">Delete</button></td></tr>');
    $('#textTable input').val('')
});

$(".deleteClass").on("click",function() {
    alert('row deleted');
});
```

Try typing anything into the textboxes. Then click on the insert button.
Then click on the delete button on the first column. Notice the alert didn't trigger even though the button has the intended class

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: use event delegation method: `$(document).on('click','.deleteClass',function(){});`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is event delegation:
Use this:

```
 $(document).on('click','.deleteClass',function()
 {
      //DELETE CODE HERE.
 });
```

Comment: you should not delegate to document if you know parent.

Comment: @dfsq Agreed,i just gave the generalized answer,it should be the NEAREST STATIC ANCESTOR.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one instead:

```
 $("#mytable").on("click",'.deleteClass',function() {
        alert('row deleted');
 });
```